# MySQL - Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, mysql

I have PHP / SQL query like this:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = ".$searchParams->firstname." AND surname = ".$searchParams->firstname."");
```

and getting error:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Dante' in 'where clause

However column Dante is not in query ( it is user input in `$searchParams->firstname`

I read on google that SQL read things revert, so from right to left,  and problem should be in apostroph or quotation marks. I try to replace a lot things but can't find the right way how to fix this.

Can someone advise me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you escape your params (I don't see even '' around the values)? ... depending on the type of your SQL connector mysql/mysqli/pdo there are different ways to escape the query..

Comment: Please read up on [How to avoid **SQL-INJECTION**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: `return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = '$searchParams->firstname' AND surname = '$searchParams->firstname'");`

Comment: Be careful you have a big MySQL injection here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your value in quotes

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `candidates` WHERE `firstname` = '".$searchParams->firstname."' AND `surname` = '".$searchParams->firstname."'");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to include input into string as below :

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM candidates WHERE firstname = '".$searchParams->firstname."' AND surname = '".$searchParams->firstname."'");
```

**Also you have passed same variable in firstname and surname, please check.**

Comment: hey thank you for answer AG21 :) You are right i try to escape this with single quotes which wasn't really helpfull